# Enviar String array a una vista mediante ViewResult

Tags: c#, asp.net, microsoft

me gustaría saber como es que puedo enviar datos mediante ViewBag o ViewData en este fragmento de código.

```
List<string> errorData = errorCodeUtil.setPageValues(httpContext, errorCode);
context.Result = new ViewResult
  {
     ViewName = "~/Views/Shared/MensajeCodigo.cshtml"
  };
```

Doy a entender que lo que quisiera enviar es el string array en el new ViewResult.

considerar que intente esto

> context.Controller.ViewBag.ErrorData = errorData;

Pero no me envía los valores a la vista.

Agradezco cualquier ayuda. Saludos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Al final, para poder obtener los datos por ViewBag se debe enviar el ViewData.

```
List<string> errorData = errorCodeUtil.setPageValues(httpContext, errorCode);                    
                context.Result = new ViewResult
                {
                    ViewName = "~/Views/Shared/MensajeCodigo.cshtml",
                    ViewData = viewData
                };
                context.Controller.ViewBag.ErrorData = errorData;
```